# how can I know if a product is directly sold by amazon with the MWS API?

Tags: api, amazon-mws

Some products are sold only through other sellers but not from Amazon directly, how can I know if a product is directly sold by Amazon with the MWS API?

Comment: Are you looking to tell if your own orders are fulfilled by amazon, or are you looking to tell if others orders are fulfilled by amazon?

Answer (score 2):

Well Amazon sells products directly, then there is Fulfilled By Amazon (FBA) where Amazon does all the work, but you ship products to their warehouses, and then there is merchant fulfilled, where the seller is responsible for packing, shipping, returns, etc.

I'm not sure how much this helps, but in the [GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/Products_GetLowestPricedOffersForASIN.html) operation in the [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/index.html), in the response, you'll receive offer(s) elements that contain an `IsFulfilledByAmazon` property.  You can use this to determine at least if it's FBA or directly sold by Amazon.

The only other way I know is to subscribe to the [AnyOfferChangedNotification](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/notifications/Notifications_AnyOfferChangedNotification.html) which will notify you in near-real time where there is a change in an offer price (top 20).  Inside those notifications, you get the seller ID. You can use that to tell if it's Amazon or not.  I use this method.